# Hiding xml object if there isn't enough room on the device's screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The main layout for an app I'm writing is on `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout` and a `FrameLayout` inside. In the `LinearLayout`, there's the buttons and text and stuff the user actually interacts with. Inside the `FrameLayout`, there's a graphic. The `FrameLayout` stays in the bottom-right corner and the `LinearLayout` is at the top.

When displayed on most different size screens, this layout works great. However, there is one device whose screen is too small and just an annoying little bit of this graphic shows. Is there a way to automatically disable an object if there isn't enough room for it in the XML? I know I could programmatically calculate it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way

Here's a the relevant parts of my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout">
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not  create a layout file for that device?

Comment: you can make your app doesn't support these small devices